# Using Mod-Rewrite in XAMPP

Tags: mod-rewrite, xampp

I've followed some tutorials on how to use `Mod_Rewrite`, but it's not working out.

I have a php index page that takes a page parameter like so:

```
call: index?page=name1, name2, name3 etc.

<?php

if (isset($_GET['page']))
{
    switch($_GET['page'])
    {
       case 'front':
       include "front.php";
       break;

       default:
       break;
       }
}
```

?>

I'd like to run mod-rewrite so that the urls display as `site.com/name1`. Is this possible with the code i'm using above?

Below is what I've been trying in the apache config files to no avail.

**apache/conf/http.conf**

```
line 122: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
line 188: DocumentRoot "G:/xampp/htdocs"
line 198: #default
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

line 215:  <Directory "G:/xampp/htdocs">
line 228:  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
line 235:  AllowOverride All

# cgi
line 355:
<Directory "G:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**G:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\http.v-hosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot G:/xampp/htdocs/
ServerName localhost
ServerAdmin admin@localhost

<Directory "G:/xampp/htdocs/localhost/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride FileInfo
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot G:/xampp/htdocs/site2/
ServerName site2.localhost
ServerAdmin admin@site2.localhost

<Directory "G:/xampp/htdocs/site2.localhost/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride FileInfo
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess file**

```
IndexIgnore *

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_rewrite can only rewrite/redirect requests. So you actually have to use `/foobar` to the outside and request `/foobar` to have mod_rewrite rewrite it internally to `/index.php?page=foobar`. That’s a common misconception people have about how mod_rewrite works.

Comment: So Gumbo if you type site.com/foobar, or link it into the url, mod_rewrite would call /index.php?page=foobar internally, and site.com/foobar is all you would see in the url? Any advice on how to achieve my original goal without mod_rewrite then? Perhaps through php?

Comment: @rrrfusco; Well, simply link to `/foobar` instead of `/index.php?page=foobar`.